# How can I update only part of a list?

Tags: angular

Context:

- Objects in a list
- List is replaced by another list with the same items plus/minus an object

Problem: Every single item in my list is destroyed and recreated even though the input is the same

The reason why the list is replaced by another list is because an observable is behind it (angularfire2). How can I avoid the entire list reloading? Is there a way of maybe creating separate observable for each item in that list and instead let those listen for changes?

Uncertain whether this should be tagged with angularfire2 since I can create the same problem in angular2. Leaving some angularfire2 in comments

Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/qSX9nRGGVNUkD5qIHOMl?p=preview

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
//import { AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<p *ngFor="let item of items | async"><test [options]="item"></test></p>'
})
export class AppComponent {
  public items = new BehaviorSubject([{bah: 1},{bah: 2},{bah: 3}]);
  //public items: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;

  constructor() {//af: AngularFire) {

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.items.next([{bah: 1},{bah: 2},{bah: 3},{bah: 4}]);
    },3000);

    /*this.items = af.database.list('/items');
    this.items.push(1);
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.items.push(2);
    },3000);*/
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'test',
  template: '{{JSON.stringify(options)}}'
})
export class TestComponent {
  public JSON = JSON;
  @Input() options;

  ngOnChanges(changes) { console.log('ngOnChanges'); }
  ngOnDestroy() { console.log('ngOnDestroy'); }
  ngOnInit() { console.log('ngOnInit'); }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to use `trackBy`?

Comment: No, I missed that but it doesn't seem to fix it? Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/d7dZ579cXQqQ4NVRAKsR?p=info

Comment: When you say 'reloading', do you refer to the variables or the visual elements?

Comment: I only care about the call to ngOnDestroy. Don't want every item to be reloaded because someone pushes something to the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `trackBy`:

```
  template: '<p *ngFor="let item of items | async; trackBy: itemToIndex" class="my-animation"><test [options]="item"></test></p>'
```

Track by should be a function, so your plnkr example should be updated to:

```
  itemToIndex(item: any){
    return item.index;
  }
```

Comment: It makes me sad inside that I have to use a function like this :P Thank you though!